# Is there a performance difference between casting to void* and a base struct pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, gcc, struct, casting

Is there a difference in performance for casting to and from a `void *` instead of casting to some base struct? This is in part to achieve a semi-dynamic typing system.

Here is my code:

```
#include "stdlib.h"

typedef struct
{
  unsigned char type;
} Dyn;

typedef struct
{
  unsigned char type;
  int number;
} Num;

typedef struct
{
  unsigned char type;
  char letter;
} Lett;

int main(void) {
  Num* n = (Num *)malloc(sizeof(Num));

  void* hold = n; // to void * casting
  Num* n_g = (Num *)hold;

  Dyn* dhold = (Dyn *)n; // to base struct casting
  Num* n_d = (Num *)dhold;
  return 0;
}
```

So in terms of pointers to structs, is there any performance difference between using `void *` or a base type struct?

Comment: Performance considerations necessarily appertain to a particular compiler, platform and settings , you would need to include more details. And maybe you could answer your question by comparing generated assembly between the different methods

Comment: Ah this would be for gcc, but i see what your saying.

Comment: I agree with M.M, to talk about performance about cast you need to provide the operating system and materiel, most of the time this operation is free. By the way, use `void *` to build this kind of feature is anti pattern in C.

Comment: This would ideally meant for cross-platform usage as it's part of an interpreter, but if there isn't a significant difference between say Linux or OSX then it's fine. I thought this might have some overheard since converting int's to floats can be expensive.

Comment: @JoshWeinstein: avoid commenting your own question, but do **edit your question** to improve it

Comment: @M.M Considering that the whole C is essentially - in practice - an asm macro language with compile-time type checking, I would say - except *very* exotic architectures - having a pointer to *anything* is the same from the asm / performance view.

Comment: @peterh I would also expect identical performance, but that's a hypothesis, I'm suggesting OP test it out

Comment: You shouldn't cast the return value of `malloc`! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is there a difference in performance for casting to and from a void* instead of casting to some base struct?

Let's assume that:

- your target platform is some common processor like x86, x86-64, ARM, Aarch, PowerPC (either 32 or 64 bits)
- you are using a good optimizing compiler (like [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) or [Clang/LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/))
- you have enabled some optimizations (so you compile with `-O1` or `-O2` at least)

Then pointers are internally represented as addresses, and you should not have any difference in performance. Study the generated assembler code (with `gcc -O1 -S -fverbose-asm` ....) to be sure.

However, you could consider using some `union` (of pointers, or better yet a pointer to `union` of `struct`).

BTW, I would recommend studying the source code of some existing [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) interpreters (e.g. [guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/), [lua](http://lua.prg/), [siod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIOD)) and reading a good book about them (e.g. [*Lisp In Small Pieces*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_in_Small_Pieces) by Queinnec)

Comment: Yea I will probably use a union for primitive types or small types